# How to mapping jsonArray to map<String,countryWiseObject>

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to load a JSON array into Map.  What I'd like to is have a Map < String,CountryWise> with the attribute name serving as the map key.

What are some ways I can do this?  I'm using Jackson.

```
 "summary": {
        "CountryWise": [
          {
            "name": "India",
            "visits": 554
          },{
            "name": "India1",
            "visits": 554
          },{
            "name": "India2",
            "visits": 554
          },{
            "name": "India3",
            "visits": 554
          }

    ],
```

.

```
public class CountryWise {
        private String name;
        private int visits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be sufficient information in the [Jackson In Five Minutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) tutorial to get this working in a number of ways. I suggest giving that a try, then updating your question if you have any specific trouble with it.